# Adding URL Scheme crashes Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, url, info.plist

I am trying to add a new URL Scheme in my Xcode project by going to Target → Info → URL Types. However, Xcode crashes every time I try to do so. This issue is also happening on my colleague's notebook and nothing could be found about this issue online. For our other Xcode projects Xcode doesn't crash when we perform the same steps. I already went over all the project build settings and I could not find anything obvious that differs from my other projects.

Relevant part of the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.{app_id_left_out_for_this_post}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Editing the Info.plist file directly to add the scheme works, but it should also work through Xcode itself (it shouldn't crash). We're seeing strange behavior with our URLs in our app (AppDelegate methods aren't called when they should be), which might have to do with this issue - maybe it's a project config setting or something like that.

Full Xcode Crash Details in case it's useful:

```
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
Process: Xcode [1516] Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier: com.apple.dt.Xcode Version: 14.3 (21812) Build Info: IDEFrameworks-21812000000000000~3 (14E222b) App Item ID: 497799835 App External ID: 855820377 Code Type: ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process: launchd [1] User ID: 501
Date/Time: 2023-05-03 17:33:55.8846 +0200 OS Version: macOS 13.3.1 (22E772610a) Report Version: 12 Anonymous UUID: E1F9FAB3-74AA-9387-B8D9-CFC697705C5E
Time Awake Since Boot: 1300 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Application Specific Information: abort() called
Application Specific Signatures: NSInvalidArgumentException
Application Specific Backtrace 0: 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000019e5ef19c __exceptionPreprocess + 176 1 DVTFoundation 0x0000000104483d84 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 392 2 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019e10e4d4 objc_exception_throw + 60 3 Foundation 0x000000019f56d2cc +[NSDirectorySubpathsOperation directorySubpathsOperationAtPath:] + 0 4 Xcode3UI 0x0000000138ef2ec0 -[Xcode3InfoEditorIconNameProvider listContents] + 384 5 Foundation 0x000000019f4c0110 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 320 6 Foundation 0x000000019f4bff78 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 220 7 Foundation 0x000000019f4bff78 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 220 8 Foundation 0x000000019f526bcc -[NSDictionary(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 404 9 Foundation 0x000000019f4bff78 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 220 10 Foundation 0x000000019f4bff78 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 220 11 IDEKit 0x0000000107e7f534 __IDEInspectorSingleValueForKeyPath_block_invoke_2 + 144 12 IDEKit 0x0000000107e7edac IDEInspectorEnumerateContent + 424 13 IDEKit 0x0000000107e7f39c IDEInspectorSingleValueForKeyPath + 244 14 IDEKit 0x0000000107bb7fb0 -[IDEInspectorListProperty refresh] + 140 15 IDEKit 0x0000000107ba457c -[IDEInspectorProperty performRefresh] + 208 16 IDEKit 0x0000000107ba2da0 __65-[IDEInspectorProperty initWithPropertyDefinition:andController:]_block_invoke + 16 17 DVTFoundation 0x00000001042d4160 -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] + 204 18 IDEKit 0x0000000107e49018 -[IDEInspectorPropertyLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 64 19 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 20 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 21 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 22 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 23 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 24 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 25 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 26 IDEKit 0x0000000107e44c60 -[IDEInspectorLayoutGroup refreshIfNeeded] + 164 27 IDEKit 0x0000000107e40a1c -[IDEInspectorContentView layoutTopDown] + 40 28 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec0c4 +[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator sendConfigureSubviewsToView:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:] + 164 29 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec344 -[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] + 256 30 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec5b8 __199-[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:]_block_invoke + 196 31 DVTFoundation 0x0000000104483a10 DVTInvokeWithFailureHintProvider + 76 32 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec424 -[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] + 480 33 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec5b8 __199-[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:]_block_invoke + 196 34 DVTFoundation 0x0000000104483a10 DVTInvokeWithFailureHintProvider + 76 35 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec424 -[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] + 480 36 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec5b8 __199-[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:]_block_invoke + 196 37 DVTFoundation 0x0000000104483a10 DVTInvokeWithFailureHintProvider + 76 38 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec424 -[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] + 480 39 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec5b8 __199-[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:]_block_invoke + 196 40 DVTFoundation 0x0000000104483a10 DVTInvokeWithFailureHintProvider + 76 41 DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x0000000103cec424 -[DVTStructuredLayoutViewCoordinator recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingVisitedViews:populatingVisitedLayoutViewsInTopDownOrder:populatingLaidOutLayoutViews:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] + 480
```

Comment: Does Xcode crash if you have a much shorter scheme in place?

Comment: Yes, it even crashes for this project when there is no URL scheme defined at all

Comment: having the same issue? have anyone solve it?

Comment: also experiencing this

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this issue? Facing the same problem.